# Code works when compiled in eclipse but not as runnable jar

Tags: java, eclipse

The code in question is below...

```
static void load() {
        ObjectInputStream ois = null;
        try {
            ois = new ObjectInputStream(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("resources/handMap.ser"));
            if (ois == null)
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "null file");
            handMap = (HashMap<Long, Integer>) ois.readObject();
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
        }
        try {
            ois.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

What it is supposed to do is load a serialized HashMap into memory. My file is in a resources folder under the src folder of my program. When i run it through eclipse there seems to be no problem. However when i run it as a runnable jar, it doesn't seem to load the file properly. I've done a few jdialogs to give me an idea of where the code is going wrong and it looks like the execution never gets past the part where it's supposed to load the file into the ObjectInputStream. Any ideas where things could be going wrong? As i mentioned, the program runs perfectly fine in Eclipse.

Comment: have you re-packaged your jar upon last correct changes?

Comment: instead of `resources/handMap.ser` use `classpath:handMap.ser`

Comment: instead of `"resources/handMap.ser"` try `"/handMap.ser"`

Comment: Remove resources

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone. Seems like the issue was the file putting it in that resource folder instead directly under the src folder.